# Linking Codeblock glut project with assimp library

Tags: c++, glut, assimp

Hello I am new with assimp and have a problem. 
When I try to include the:

```
#include <assimp/cimport.h>
```

`#include <assimp/scene.h>`

`#include <assimp/postprocess.h>`

in a c++ glut project it says No such file or directory, so I obviously need to link some libraries to the project. The question is where can I find that library.
I downloaded assimp view 3.0 and opened the object i need to inport in c++ with it and so far it look ok.

http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/usage.html .. Is the link to how to use assimp with c++ but no info how to link it

Comment: Which IDE are you using? You need to tell the IDE where to search for the #include files. Each IDE has its own settings for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should have read up on the very site you linked.

http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/install.html

These are installation directions. The very top looks like it talks about using prebuilt libraries and telling you what to link into your visual studio project.

One last note: you are using the c interface according to your question. After reading the documentation I see that they have a C++ specific importer header you may want to use instead.

`#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>`

**EDIT:** This answer assumes you are using visual studio of course. However, that link also provides building from scratch instructions as well as other ways of building and installing the library. So if you are a linux/unix user I imagine you can make do with these instructions.

Comment: I did exactly that, it's failing. Posted on SO. Could you check it out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56613212/assimp-import-failing-on-xcode