# assimp import failing on Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, assimp

### What I'm trying to do

... to import assimp, specifically:

```cpp
#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>
#include <assimp/scene.h>
#include <assimp/postprocess.h>
```

and some other assimp headers.

I'm using **xcode 10.2.1**.

The errors im getting:

[image]

### What I tried

- I imported assimp in Link Binary With Libraries, which was installed with `brew install assimp`
- I reinstalled assimp with `brew reinstall assimp`, just in case.

[image]

Nothing has changed. Xcode still can't resolve the dependency.

I tried deleting the import the error is pointing on, but it just showed up at the next assimp import again, as in, xcode can't resolve the import, even though I added `libassimp4.1.0.dylib` from `/usr/local/Cellar/assimp/4.1.0/lib`. I'm lost here. This is supposed to work, but it doesn't. I imported other libs this way and never had an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I fixed it and this is how:

I fixed the compiler error by pointing xcode to the headers. It somehow didn't work with the homebrew installation, so I added this manually.

In your App settings, go to:  **build settings**

scroll down to: **search paths**

there, find: **header search paths**

double click on it, then add by clicking **+**

add: `/usr/local/Cellar/assimp/4.1.0/include` as **non-recursive**

### Disclaimer:

Depending on how you installed it or if or if not you installed Homebrew systemwide, which is not recommended, assimp might live in a different directory. In my case it was `/usr/local/Cellar/`